# Qt Signal/Slot connections cause increase in CPU usage of application?

Tags: qt, qt-signals

I have a GUI application developed in Qt for a embedded system, I have many signal/slot `Qt::queuedconnections` present in my application. After running my application over a long period of time I am observing that the CPU usage of my system is linearly increasing over period of time, which is causing my application to respond slower.

Am not disconnecting these signal/slots connections. The increase in CPU usage is anywhere related to dynamically creating signal/slots ? Is there any method or way to test the signal/slot memory or CPU usage. ?

Comment: What does your profiler say?

Comment: Signal/slots are mere function calls (if of type DirectConnection, which is default for single-threaded usage), depending on what the functions do, that might result in linearly increasing CPU usage. If the number of objects or number of connections increases over time, so might the CPU usage. Try with a profiler to see where the time is spent.

Comment: sounds like memory leak to me.

Comment: Yep It was a memory leak. I figured it out. Thanks to all for your valuable responses.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt the slow comes from you Signals/Slots since (quoted from [the doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qobject.html#disconnect)):

> A signal-slot connection is removed when either of the objects involved are destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

Some event(the paintevent for example) might be getting called in a loop, which leads to increase in CPU usage. Check if any event is associated with the "connections". Like other answers above, signal/slots do not lead to increase in CPU usage.

Answer (score 0):

It was a memory leak problem, and not related to the signal/slot connections as I suspected. I figured it out using valgrind.